# Limit form submissions based on form selections

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, form-submit, submission

I have a consumer website that gives users an approval form that I want allow the users to submit their approvals but I want to limit the form number submissions based on the certain selections made and a combination of previous selections submitted. As of now, the users always have access to the form even after they approve it and I would like to stop submissions after they approve it.

There are 3 set of selections:

**Set 1** [Initial Options at first, none of the other sets should be shown.]

Approve (radio button)

Disapprove (radio button)

**Set 2** [This set is dependent on Set 1's selection. If the "Disapprove" from Set 1 is selected, then this set should be shown. Otherwise it will be hidden.]

Revision (radio button)

Correction (radio button)

**Set 3** [This set is dependent on Set 2's selection (and of course Set 2 being visible). If the "Revision" or "Correction" is selected from Set 1, then show either "Revision text" or "Correction text" based on the corresponding selection from set 2.]

Revision text (textarea)

Correction text (textarea)

Set 2 is dependent on Set 1's, and Set 3 is dependent on Set 2's selection.

**Ok, these are the submission total I would like based on the selections:**

- If the user...**first approves**, dynamically **set the total submissions to 1**. Form will not submit the next time, counting the current submission as 1.
- If the user...**first disapproves**, dynamically **set the total submissions to 2**. Remaining one more submission, counting the the current submission as 1.
- If the user...**first approves and then disapproves**, dynamically **set the total submissions to 3**. Remaining one more submission, counting the the current submission as 1.
- If the user...**first disapproves and then approves**, dynamically **set the total submissions to 2**. Remaining one more submission, counting the the current submission as 1.
- If the user...**first disapproves and then chooses revision**, **show the revision textarea** and  dynamically **set the total submissions to 2**. Remaining one more submission, counting the the current submission as 1.
- If the user...**first disapproves and then chooses correction**, **show the correction textarea** and dynamically **set the total submissions to 2**. Remaining one more submission, counting the the current submission as 1.

This is the general pattern I would want to the submission limits. So basically, if the user approves they can no longer submit the form after the current submission. If the user disapproves they are only allowed 2 additional submissions. I haven't fully worked it out, but Im hoping to get some suggestions and help from some experts.

Another thing to consider are any alternatives if the user has javascript disabled and their cookies turned off (if the given solution requires them.)

Comment: It's not going to be easy to help you come up with a non-JS solution if we don't know what language you're using server-side... Can you also explain exactly which bit you're having problems with? calculating how many submissions they're allowed/counting them/??? What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: In addition, can you clarify what you mean by submissions? eg in your last scenario, the user disapproves, then corrects, adds some text and finally submits the form - What should happen next? They get exactly the same form back so they can submit it again? Or are you envisaging a "submit" after each option?

Comment: @Basiclife, thanks for the input. I really wanted a unique solution fit for my situation that's why I didn't include a solution, which I dont have (the reason for my post). Im developing in php and would a js solution (with an if-disabled workaround) or a non-js solution. As for the solution being js or non-js, it wasn't a request just saying that *if* the solution was javascript based or dependent on cookies being enabled, what would be the work arounds if they weren't enabled, as I see these type of form solutions are either js based that depend on cookies remembering the user's info.

Comment: Im open to all suggestions, but want to know if there are any workarounds that I should know about...To answer your question about submissions, I mean whenever a selection is made and the form is submitted. That's what a submission is. What I shouldve mention is that each subsequent option set is dependent on the previous. So Set 2 is dependent on Set 1's, and Set 3 is dependent on Set 2's selection. Im sure I explained what should happen in each scenario. They on thing I need to mention is that *when* the limit is reached, that an error message should come up with custom message by me.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with "no javascript", you need to make the site work without script support. That is always a good first step. All your validation and logic must be replicated on the server anyway because you have no control over the client.

Once you have the page working without script, you can then script the client (say by doing submissions with AJAX) to provide a more functional or efficient user interface.

Comment: Paraphrasing: "To deal with no JavaScript, you need to make your site work without JavaScript". Circular much?

Comment: @RobG, thanks. I did consider ajax but never developed in it so, was hoping for some examples or solutions using that language.

Comment: @gdinaro AJAX is really easy - think of it as your browser requesting a page from the server, except that instead of displaying it to the user, javascript gets the contents as a stringxml document. If you're going down the JS route, get jQuery which makes it even easier - 1 line of code :) `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Basiclife - an XMLHttpRequest returns a text string that might be XML or it might not. It is often JSON. A typical AJAX library is about 50 lines of code, you don't need the 4,000 lines of jQuery just for that.

Comment: @RobG I know - I've written one myself which supported multiple simultaneous async requests - but jQuery is easy to use, well documented and has a myriad other benefits. Also, to clarify, that was supposed to read string/xml document - In fact it's all just a string really but since the topic is AJA{X}, I thought it sensible to mention xml.